# Spring cloud gateway redis rate limiter don't work

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I cannot play with ratelimiter of spring cloud gateway.
Here I config gateway:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
      #Admin
      - id: haft-upms-admin
        uri: lb://haft-upms-admin
        predicates:
        - Path=/admin/**
        filters:
        - name: RequestRateLimiter
          args:
            key-resolver: '#{@remoteAddrKeyResolver}'
            redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
            redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1
        - name: Hystrix
          args:
            name: default
            fallbackUri: 'forward:/fallback'
```

I use JMeter to call API loop 1000 times but gateway not response 429 too many request in response.
Where I wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, your access url are wrong, which can not match route `id:haft-upms-admin`, so can not invoke redis `RequestRateLimiter`. You can see debug log like: 
[image], you can check if match route id.

Secondly, you can read my config file:
[image]

Path is:`localhost:xxxx/eureka-client/XXXX`
will forward to my service eureka-client
and match route id my_coute1, so you can refer to my sample
all in all, you must match you route id.